# [__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, cordova

I am totally new to XCODE, got this error message. Could you help me to solve it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVHvk.png)

> 2018-12-08 21:46:22.258801-0500 IAOGI English App[653:6168]
>   DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file:
>   file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/753BE612-F65B-44E8-A727-347043E8736A/data/Containers/Data/Application/8D1AD8A3-6384-48C0-8C1C-29F27E098D80/Library/Cookies/com.iaogcan.english.binarycookies
>
> 2018-12-08 21:46:23.175378-0500 IAOGI English App[653:6168] Apache
>   Cordova native platform version 4.5.5 is starting.
>
> 2018-12-08 21:46:23.177968-0500 IAOGI English App[653:6168]
>   Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>
> 2018-12-08 21:46:23.210797-0500 IAOGI English App[653:6168]
>   -[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000040df20
>
> 2018-12-08 21:46:23.277812-0500 IAOGI English App[653:6168] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM
>   cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60000040df20'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d54b1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cabb735
>   objc_exception_throw + 48
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d569f44
>   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>
> 3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d54fed6
>   ***forwarding*** + 1446
>
> 4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d551da8
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>
> 5   IAOGI English App                   0x000000010a9cacc7
>   -[CDVViewController viewDidLoad] + 199
>
> 6   IAOGI English App                   0x000000010a955df6
>   -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] + 54
>
> 7   UIKitCore                           0x000000011acc14e1
>   -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1186
>
> 8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011acc1940
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27
>
> 9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011b318c53 -[UIWindow
>   addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122
>
> 10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b31936e -[UIWindow
>   _setHidden:forced:] + 294
>
> 11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b32c5c0 -[UIWindow
>   makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
>
> 12  IAOGI English App                   0x000000010a9cf4d0
>   -[CDVAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 752
>
> 13  IAOGI English App                   0x000000010a955b73
>   -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 195
>
> 14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2d7bde
>   -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 280
>
> 15  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2d95cb
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3979
>
> 16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2dec2f
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1623
>
> 17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011aafd4e9
>   __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 866
>
> 18  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ab0629c
>   +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
>
> 19  UIKitCore                           0x000000011aafd126
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 233
>
> 20  UIKitCore                           0x000000011aafdae0
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1085
>
> 21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011aafbcb5
>   __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 795
>
> 22  UIKitCore                           0x000000011aafb95f
>   -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435
>
> 23  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ab00a90
>   __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 584
>
> 24  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ab0180e
>   _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
>
> 25  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ab007ef
>   -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
>   + 221
>
> 26  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ab0593a
>   -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
>
> 27  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2dd44e
>   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
>
> 28  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ae81d09
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 357
>
> 29  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116c1d2da
>   -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
>
> 30  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116c28443
>   __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 271
>
> 31  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116c27b3a
>   __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
>
> 32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f8cc602
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>
> 33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f8cfb78
>   _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301
>
> 34  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116c5cba8
>   **FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 30
>
> 35  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116c5c860
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457
>
> 36  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116c5ce40
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
>
> 37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4b0721
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>
> 38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4aff93
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
>
> 39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4aa63f
>   __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
>
> 40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4a9e11
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
>
> 41  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001128761dd
>   GSEventRunModal + 62
>
> 42  UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2e081d
>   UIApplicationMain + 140
>
> 43  IAOGI English App                   0x000000010a955a91 main + 65
>
> 44  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f942575 start + 1
>
> 45  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates that the [CordovaPreferences category](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/NSDictionary%2BCordovaPreferences.h) isn't being loaded. That suggests this is being linked statically, but the `-objc` flag wasn't passed to the linker. See [QA1490: Building Objective-C static libraries with categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1490/_index.html). I'm not familiar with Cordova's build system, but this suggests you've perhaps bypassed it, or the project settings are corrupted. (I've never touched Cordova in my life, and I don't know anything about how it builds other than its instructions indicate there's some special build step.)

The important part of this stack is this frame:

```
5 IAOGI English App 0x000000010a9cacc7 -[CDVViewController viewDidLoad] + 199
```

This is the last frame preceding the generic assertion logic. Searching for "CDVViewController" in GitHub brings us to [CDVViewController.m](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVViewController.m). Its `-viewDidLoad` includes:

```
id backupWebStorage = [self.settings cordovaSettingForKey:@"BackupWebStorage"];
```

Looking up `settings` shows it's an `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSMutableDictionary* settings;
```

Since `cordovaSettingForKey:` isn't a standard method on `NSMutableDictionary`, it is very likely a category method, which we can find with a little more hunting in the source code. The file follows the standard naming pattern: `NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.h` (a class and category name separated by a `+`).

Comment: i have the same problem but this resolution doesn't work for me.  Could you take a look at my stack post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293865/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-running